# Don't automatically build changes from a certain directory with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

We have a branch policy setup to automatically build our pull requests to a certain branch.

This is great, but when we commit documentation changes, which are in a specific directory (~/docs/), I'd like to not trigger an entire build of the platform.

I can't find any way to not build on pull request if the changes are only in a specific directory... does this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Trigger, just add an exclude for the path to your documents.  This will cause the 'trigger' to ignore any changes that happen in the given path.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that'll affect the entire Build. I was hoping I could re-use an existing Build definition and simply control whether or not a change triggers it based on a branch policy. I'll accept this anyway since it's the closest thing.

Comment: @mariocatch I am not understanding exactly what you are trying to do because the above with the pull request policy should do what you are asking.

Comment: Because the answer you proposed is at the Build Definition level, and not at the Branch Policy level, that means any changes made to the Build Definition will affect all builds that use it, not just pull requests to the branch using that Branch Policy. Make sense? So I suppose we're forced to create more than one Build Definition, where one is just to be used by the Branch Policy.

Comment: @mariocatch I do see what you are asking/saying now.  Yes, what you are looking for is not currently an available option in VSTS.  I would recommend you raise a suggestion for it here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services